# Why isn´t the TYPE_STEP_COUNTER sensor not working on Motorola devices?

Tags: android, android-sensors, motorola

I've been searching an answer for days and I can´t find anything.

The problem is, I've made a very simple Android app to count steps. It's working on Sony and LG devices but not on Motorola devices (tried on a couple 2nd and 3rd gen Moto X).

I get the "sensor or listener is null" message.

Here is my code, any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
package com.xxx.yyy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private TextView textView;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;
    private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(19,true);
//        mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
//        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor);
//        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        float[] values = event.values;
        int value = -1;

        if (values.length > 0) {
            value = (int) values[0];
        }

        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
            textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + value);
        } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
            // For test only. Only allowed value is 1.0 i.e. for step taken
//            textView.setText("Step Detector Detected : " + value);
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

}
```

Comment: did you solve your problem?
Maybe you have to check your Motorola android version. Lower version then 4.4 (if i'm not mistaken) or older phone don't have the sensor.